# How to use chrome.storage and runtime.connect in a Firefox WebExtensions add-on

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm trying to create a Firefox add-on that does the following:

- sends a message to a background script when the page body is clicked
- the sent message is stored by the background script
- the stored message is retrieved by the background script
- when the add-in browser button is clicked that stored message is sent from the background script to the content script
- the content script displays the received message

I'm using Firefox version 48 for Windows and I can't get it to work.  Can someone point out what I'm doing wrong please.

Here is my content script:

```
// setup message channel between this script and background script
var msgPort = chrome.runtime.connect({name:"msgPort"});

// fires when background script sends a message
msgPort.onMessage.addListener(function(msg) {
    console.log(msg.txt);
});

// sends a message to background script when page is clicked
document.body.addEventListener("click", function() {
    msgPort.postMessage({txt: "page clicked"});
});
```

Here is my background script:

```
var msgPort;
var tmp;

// fires when message port connects to this background script
function connected(prt)
{
    msgPort = prt;
    msgPort.postMessage({txt: "message channel established"});
    msgPort.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage);
}

// fires when content script sends a message
frunction gotMessage(msg)
{
    // store the message
    chrome.storage.local.set({message : msg.txt});

    // read the stored message back again
    chrome.storage.local.get("message", function(item){
        tmp = item;
    });
}

// send the saved message to the content script when the add-on button is clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    msgPort.postMessage({txt: "saved message: "+tmp});
});

chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(connected);
```

And here is my manifest:

```
{
    "name": "test",

    "manifest_version": 2,

    "version": "1.0",

    "permissions": ["activeTab","storage"],

    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Go"
    },

    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
        "id": "test@example.com",
        "strict_min_version": "48.0a1"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please define "can't get it to work". What issue are you experiencing? What is the output in the Browser Console?

Comment: Just to double check: Are you aware that `storage.local` is directly available to the content script? I've been assuming that you have been accessing it in the background script for investigation/learning/demo of `runtime.connect`.  It may be that my assumption was incorrect, and that you were not aware `storage.local` could be accessed by your content scripts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While there may be other issues elsewhere in your code, one issue is that you are not accounting for the fact that [`chrome.storage.local.set`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Storage/StorageArea/set) is asynchronous.

As your code is, your call to [`chrome.storage.local.get`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Storage/StorageArea/get) is being executed immediately after your request to store data via `chrome.storage.local.set` without waiting for the data to actually be stored. Thus, the data may not yet be available.

Your `gotMessage(msg)` function should look more like:

```js
function gotMessage(msg)
{
    // store the message
    chrome.storage.local.set({message : msg.txt}, function(){
        // read the stored message back again
        chrome.storage.local.get("message", function(item){
            tmp = item;
            //Indicate that the data is available
            //Only do this if you desire.
            //chrome.browserAction.setTitle({title:'Send data to content script'});
        });
    });
}
```

Note: there is also a syntax error in your question where `frunction gotMessage(msg)` should be `function gotMessage(msg)`.

**`storage.local` is available to content scripts:**
You are currently passing messages back and forth to between your content script and background script in order to `set()` and `get()` the contents of `storage.local` within your background script. I am assuming that you are doing that to test `runtime.connect`, `browser_action`, etc.. Another possibility is that you are not aware that you can `get` and `set` with `storage.local` from your content script.

### Fully functional code:

There were also multiple other issues.  Most of the issues were the result of either the somewhat complex sequence of actions that *was* needed on the part of the user to get it to work. Some of what was required is due to some peculiarities of WebExtensions/Firefox.:

1. Fully remove any old version of the add-on previously installed

   1. From `about:addons` (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>A</kbd> on OSX), "remove" the add-on.
   2. Refresh all content pages (or at least any on which you are testing). This removes any injected content scripts from the previous installation. Content scripts are *not* removed automatically by Firefox when the add-on is removed/disabled.
2. Reload the temporary add-on from `about:debugging`.
3. Refresh the page on which you were testing.  This was needed because when the add-on was re-loaded, the content script was injected first. In the content script, you do [`runtime.connect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Runtime/connect). This will not connect if there is not *first* a [`runtime.onConnect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/onConnect) listener. Thus, as it was the content script *had* to be loaded after the background script.
4. Click on the content page
5. Click on the `browser_action` button`

Without knowing that you needed to perform exactly this sequence, it is difficult to get it to do what you wanted it to do.

A significant part of the difficulty in figuring out what was going on is that you had a considerable amount of state information which was only contained within the code. No indications were being made to the user as to what state the content script, or the background script were in. In order to help visualize what is happening in each of the scripts, I have added a significant number of calls to `console.log` to better illustrate what is happening within your scripts.

I have significantly modified the code:

1. When trying to send a message (due to the page being clicked) recognize that a connection has not been made, and try again to obtain a connection (Result: No longer need to do #3 in the user sequence above).
2. Disables itself if it detects it had a connection and lost it.  The most likely cause of that circumstance is that the affected content script was orphaned by the add-on being reloaded. (Result: No longer need to do #1 in the sequence above; can re-load the add-on without removing the old version/reloading content pages first.)
3. There were other issues in the code. I believe I added comments to the code sufficient to explain them.

The output that is now generated in the Browser Console is:

```
1471884197092 addons.xpi WARN Addon with ID demo-runtime.connect-and-storage.local@example.com already installed, older version will be disabled
        content: Content script injected.
        content: Making message port available for connection
alert() is not supported in background windows; please use console.log instead.
Open the Browser Console.
background: In background script.
background: listening for a connection
        content: page clicked
        content: Sending message failed: not yet connected
        content: Retrying connection for message: Object { type: "page clicked" }
        content: Making message port available for connection
background: Port connected: sending confirmation message: Object { type: "message channel established" }
        content: Received message: type: message channel established  
        content: Sending pending message Object { type: "page clicked" }
        content: Sending message Object { type: "page clicked" }
background: Received message: Object { type: "page clicked" }
background: Got data from storage.local.get: Object { message: "page clicked" }
background: Button clicked sending message: Object { type: "saved message", data: "page clicked" }
        content: Received message: type: saved message 
                          message: data: page clicked
```

*manifest.json*:

```json
{
    "name": "Demo runtime.connect and storage.local",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "0.1",
    "permissions": ["activeTab","storage"],
    "content_scripts": [
        {
            "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
            "js": ["content.js"]
        }
    ],

    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },

    "browser_action": {
        "default_title": "Data not yet available",
        "browser_style": true
    },

    "applications": {
        "gecko": {
        "id": "demo-runtime.connect-and-storage.local@example.com",
        "strict_min_version": "48.0a1"
        }
    }
}
```

*background.js*:

```js
//* For testing, open the Browser Console
try{
    //Alert is not supported in Firefox. This forces the Browser Console open.
    //This abuse of a misfeature works in FF49.0b+, not in FF48
    alert('Open the Browser Console.');
}catch(e){
    //alert throws an error in Firefox versions below 49
    console.log('Alert threw an error. Probably Firefox version below 49.');
}
//*
console.log('background: In background script.');

var msgPort;
var dataFromStorage;

// Fires when message port connects to this background script
function connected(prt) {
    msgPort = prt;
    msgPort.onMessage.addListener(gotMessage); //This should be done first
    let message = {type: "message channel established"};
    console.log('background: Port connected: sending confirmation message:', message);
    msgPort.postMessage(message);
}

//Fires when content script sends a message
//Syntax error this line (misspelled function)
function gotMessage(msg) {
    console.log('background: Received message:', msg);
    // store the message
    chrome.storage.local.set({message : msg.type}, function(){
        // read the stored message back again
        chrome.storage.local.get("message", function(item){
            console.log('background: Got data from storage.local.get:',item);
            //You were setting tmp (now dataFromStorage) to the item object, not the
            //  message key which you requested.
            /*
            for(x in item){
                console.log('background: property of item:',x);
            }
            //*/
            dataFromStorage = item.message;
            //Indicate to the user that the data is available
            chrome.browserAction.setTitle({title:'Send data to content script'});
        });
    });
}

// send the saved message to the content script when the add-on button is clicked
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function() {
    //msgPort not defined unless user has clicked on page
    if(msgPort) {
        let message = {type: "saved message",data:dataFromStorage};
        console.log('background: Button clicked sending message:', message);
        msgPort.postMessage(message);
    } else {
        console.log('background: No message port available (yet).');
    }
});

//Be open to establishing a connection.  This must be done prior to the
//  chrome.runtime.connect elsewhere in your code. 
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(connected);
console.log('background: Listening for a connection');
```

*content.js*:

```js
console.log('\tcontent: Content script injected.');

var isConnected=false;
var retryConnectionTimerId=-1; //In case we want to cancel it
var retryConnectionCount=0;
var messageBeingRetried=null;

//setup message channel between this script and background script
var msgPort;

function messageListener(msg){
    //Using a closure for this function is a bad idea.  This should be a named
    //  function defined at the global scope so we can remove it as a
    //  listener if the background script sends a message to disconnect.
    //  You need to be able to disable any active content scripts if the 
    //  add-on is disabled/removed.  This is a policy from Mozilla. However,
    //  for WebExtensions it is not yet possible due to the current lack of the 
    //  runtime.onSuspend event.
    if(typeof msg === 'object' && msg.hasOwnProperty('type')){
        //Should look specifically for the message indicating connection.
        console.log('\tcontent: Received message: type:', msg.type
            ,(msg.hasOwnProperty('data') ? '\n\t\t\t  Message: data:':'')
            ,(msg.hasOwnProperty('data') ? msg.data : '')
        );
        if(msg.type === 'disableAddon'){
            //Allow for the background script to disable the add-on.
            disableThisScript('Received disableAddon message');
        }
        if(isConnected && msg.type === 'message channel established'){
            //We are in a content script that is left over from a previous load
            //  of this add-on. Or, at least that is the most likely thing 
            //  while testing.  This probably needs to change for a real add-on.
            //  This is here because reloading the temporary add-on does not
            //  auto-disable any content scripts.
            disableThisScript('Received second channel established message');
            return;
        }//else
        isConnected=true; //Any correctly formatted message received indicates connection
        //Immediately send a message that was pending (being retried).
        //  Note: This only immediately sends the message which was most recently attempted
        //  to send via sendMessage, not all messages which might be waiting in timers.
        //  Any others will be sent when their timers expire.
        sendPendingMessageIfPending();
    }else{
        console.log('\tcontent: Received message without a "type":', msg);
    }
}

function receiveDisconnect(){
    //The port was disconnected
    disableThisScript('Port disconnected');
    isConnected=false;
}

function makePortAvailableForConnection(){
    console.log('\tcontent: Making message port available for connection');
    if(msgPort && typeof msgPort.disconnect === 'function'){
        //Call disconnect(), if we have already tried to have a connection
        msgPort.disconnect();
    }
    //Try to make a connection. Only works if ocConnect listener
    //  is already established.
    msgPort = chrome.runtime.connect({name:"msgPort"});
    //Fires when background script sends a message
    msgPort.onMessage.addListener(messageListener);
    msgPort.onDisconnect.addListener(receiveDisconnect);
    //Can not use runtime.onConnect to detect that we are connected.
    //  It only fires if some other script is trying to connect
    //  (using chrome.runtime.connect or chrome.tabs.connect)
    //  to this script (or generally). It does not fire when the connection
    //  is initiated by this script.
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(portConnected); //Does not fire
}

function portConnected(){
    //This event does not fire when the connection is initiated,
    //  chrome.runtime.connect() from this script.
    //  It is left in this code as an example and to demonstrate that the event does
    //  not fire.
    console.log('\tcontent: Received onConnect event');
    isConnected=true;
}

// sends a message to background script when page is clicked
function sendClickMessage() {
    console.log('\tcontent: Page clicked');
    sendMessage({type: "page clicked"});
            chrome.storage.local.get("message", function(item){
            console.log('content: Got data from storage.local.get:',item);
            });

}

function clearPendingMessage(){
    window.clearTimeout(retryConnectionTimerId);
    messageBeingRetried=null;
}

function sendPendingMessageIfPending() {
    //Pending messages should really be implemented as a queue with each message
    //  being retried X times and then sent once a connection is made. Right now
    //  this works for a single message.  Any other messages which were pending
    //  are only pending for the retry period and then they are forgotten.
    if(messageBeingRetried !== null && retryConnectionTimerId){
        let message = messageBeingRetried;
        clearPendingMessage();
        console.log('\tcontent: Going to send pending message', message);
        sendMessage(message);
    }
}

function retryingMessage(message) {
    retryConnectionTimerId=-1;
    messageBeingRetried=null;
    sendMessage(message);
}

function sendMessage(message) {
    if(isConnected){
        try{
            console.log('\tcontent: Sending message', message);
            msgPort.postMessage(message);
            retryConnectionCount=0;
        }catch(e){
            if(e.message.indexOf('disconnected port') > -1){
                console.log('\tcontent: Sending message failed: disconnected port');
                if(isConnected){
                    console.log('\tcontent: Had connection, but lost it.'
                                + ' Likely add-on reloaded. So, disable.');
                    disableThisScript('Add-on likely reloaded.');
                }else{
                    retryConnection(message);
                }
            }else{
                console.log('\tcontent: Sending message failed: Unknown error', e);
            }
        }
    }else{
        console.log('\tcontent: Sending message failed: not yet connected');
        retryConnection(message);
    }
}

function retryConnection(message){
    if(retryConnectionCount>=5){
        //Limit the number of times we retry the connection.
        //  If the connection is not made by now, it probably won't be
        //  made at all.  Don't fill up the console with a lot of
        //  messages that might make it harder to see what is happening.
        retryConnectionCount=0; //Allow more retries upon another click event.
        //The current message is forgotten. It is now just discarded.
        return;
    }
    console.log('\tcontent: Retrying connection for message:', message);
    makePortAvailableForConnection();
    //Try sending the message after a timeout.
    //  This will result in the repeated attempts to
    //  connect and send the message.
    messageBeingRetried=message;
    retryConnectionTimerId = window.setTimeout(retryingMessage,500,message);
    retryConnectionCount++;
}

function disableThisScript(reason){
    console.log('\tcontent: Disable the content script:', reason);
    //Gracefully disable everything previously set up.
    msgPort.onMessage.removeListener(messageListener);
    msgPort.onDisconnect.removeListener(receiveDisconnect);
    try{
        msgPort.disconnect();
    }catch(e){
        //most likely the port was already disconnected
    }
    chrome.runtime.onConnect.removeListener(portConnected);
    document.body.removeEventListener("click", sendClickMessage);
    isConnected=false;
}

//Making the connection available will silently fail if there is not already a
//  onConnect listener in the background script.  In the case of a "temporary"
//  add-on upon load or reload, the content script is run first and
//  no connection is made.
makePortAvailableForConnection();

document.body.addEventListener("click", sendClickMessage);
```

**NOTE:**
This works for a demo, or learning, but won't work well for use in a production extension. There is nothing in the code that accounts for having more than one tab.

You are sending messages to a content script based on clicking on the `browser_action` button.  This means that you need to be able to explicitly send the message from the background script only to the content script that is in the tab being displayed in the active window at the time the user clicks the `browser_action` button. For example, the user might be in one page, click on the content, then switch to another tab, and click on the `browser_action` button.  In this case, the message should be sent to the currently active tab, not the one which was switched away from (which made the connection).

While you could track the tab which was active when you received the connection or click message (which would work because the connection is actually made, or a message sent, based on a click event (which is assumed to be user input)), it might be better to use [`tabs.connect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/connect) which allows you to establish a connection only with a specific tab. Knowing which [`runtime.Port`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/Runtime/Port) corresponds to each tab will allow you to be sure you are sending messages only to the tab which was active at the time the `browser_action` button was clicked. You would need to keep an array, or object, that contained the connected ports indexed by tab ID.

Comment: Makyen - this is excellent information and has helped me understand a lot of things.  However, I am getting the repeated errors: "content:sending message failed: not yet connected" and "content:Retrying connection for message:Object { type="page clicked"}"

Comment: I've added a "isConnected=true;" as the last line of makeConnection and that has stopped the repeated messages.  Now I get "content: page clicked" and "content: sending message Object { type: "page clicked" }" when I click the page.  And I get nothing when I click the browser action button.  I have yet to figure out how to see the console.log output from background scripts.

Comment: I have also upgrade to FF 48.0.1 to see if that made any difference.

Comment: @Graham, You can see the output of `console.log()` in the  [Browser Console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Browser_Console) (Ctrl-Shift-J, or Cmd-Shift-J on OSX). When testing WebExtensions, I routinely abuse a misfeature to cause the extesnsion to open that console.  The `alert()` function is not supported in background scripts, but will open the Browser Console and output the alert text in the console. For testing, I often include in my background scripts a line like: `window.alert('Open the console.'); //for testing`

Comment: @Graham, The WebExtensions API is very much still in development. What is working improves with each version of Firefox. For now, you are probably best off developing and testing your WebExtension add-on with [Firefox Developer Edition](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/developer/), or [Firefox Nightly](https://nightly.mozilla.org/). You should also make careful note of what version of Firefox is required for the functionality you desire to use. This information is contained in the "Browser compatibility" section of the MDN documentation pages.

Comment: Cheers Makyen - I'll give FF developer version a spin.  According to the docs this should work on version 48.

Comment: @Graham, It looks like a combination of all the above resulted in me setting you up for failure.  Sorry about that. As it turns out, `alert()` throws an error in FF48.  By FF49.0b5, it does what I expected.  I have added a `try{}catch(e){}` block to cover the `alert()` in *background.js* and tested in FF48.

Comment: @Graham, As to adding `isConnected=true;` to the end of `makeConnection`: That would defeat the current purpose of that variable.  That variable is used as a flag to indicate that there is *actually* a connection established, not just attempted on the content script's side.

Comment: @Graham, I updated the code, again. It now limits the number of retries per message, immediately sends a single pending message when the connection is made.  I also added a note that it might be better to use `tabs.connect()` if you are going to be sending a message specifically to the content script in the active tab (e.g. on press of the `browser_action` button).