# How to listen to button's click event on a Google Chrome's extension's HTML on the content script and manipulate the DOM of the webpage opened?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

For the Chrome extension that i am trying to make, basically i need to manipulate the content of the webpage currently open. I am able to send messages from the script inserted in the content and receive them in the background JS and send a response which i can log and check in the content JS. There are 3 JS files, 1 is the content JS -> content.js (containing code for receiving messages), 1 is the background.js (containing code for sending messages) and the third script is the dashboard.js which is included in the html of the default_popup html page. 
I am able to listen to the click event of a button on the popup of the extension on the script that i have included on the page (dashboard.js). 
The problem is that if i include the code for sending messages to the client script from this file dashboard.js, it doesn't fire or it is not received on the content script (content.js), either way the onMessage listener does not fire on the button's click.
I have tried the answer to similar questions but i still am not able to receive messages on the content script on clicking a button on the popup.

Also, the listener to click event of the button on the popup never fires when the function for it is written in the content script, the button returns undefined by jQuery, maybe because the content script does not cover the popup's JS and it's an issue of scope? 
Overall, I need to send messages to the client script specifically on clicking a button on the popup. This is the code i have used

**manifest.json**

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name":    "Test Extension",
"version": "0.0",

"background": {
    "persistent": false,
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},

"content_scripts": [{
    "matches":    ["*://*/*"],
    "js":         ["jquery.js", "content.js"]
}],

"browser_action": {
  "default_icon": "icon.png",
  "default_popup": "dashboard.html"
}
}
```

**dashboard.js**

```
var port   =   chrome.runtime.connect({name: "popup-body"});
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#button').click(function(){  
    console.log('button clicked');
    port.postMessage({status:"clicked on button"});

   });  
});
```

**background.js**

```
chrome.runtime.onConnect.addListener(function(port){
  console.log('onConnect');
  port.postMessage({status:"background Js active"});
});
```

**content.js**

```
// content script, works on the page open
var port = chrome.runtime.connect({name:"mycontentscript"});
port.onMessage.addListener(function(message,sender){
   console.log('got message');
   console.log(message);
});
```

**dashboard.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <script src="jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="dashboard.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form>
            <input type="button" id="button" value="Click To Send" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now on opening a new tab i can see message object in the console of the page ( using content.js) that was sent from the background (background.js). How do i make the same thing happen using by clicking on the button 'Click To Send'? Also, 2 way communication is possible between the background.js and content.js but how to control the same using the events on the popup? Eventually, i need to make changes on the DOM of the opened webpage, but i reckon i will be able to do that once the message is received in the content.js.

Comment: Each `connect` creates a new port but you don't store it in separate variables in background script.

Comment: I have added the listener in the background script so it would respond to a  message from the content script, which it does, to test this i sent a message from the content script after a timeout and the background script   received it

Comment: ...and your background script doesn't relay the messages from content script to popup and vice versa.

Comment: Yes, that's right. I need the messages to be emitted due to an event on the popup (click of a button), now i'm assuming this will need the messages to be sent from the JavaScript file included in the popup (dashboard.js), is that right? Or can i give the popup access to the background js, so it listens to the click and sends the message to the content script?

Comment: Uhm, are you sure you understand [the architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)? Background page is a separate thing. Your background page port listener listens to the popup and content script but it serves no purpose because you don't store the ports into separate variables to make it possible to relay a message.

Comment: Why are you using [runtime.connect()](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-connect)/[port](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#type-Port)? Using them is helping to confuse you. Using it correctly is *significantly* more complex than using [`runtime.sendmessage()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-sendMessage)/[tabs.sendMessage](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-sendMessage())  I would *strongly* recommend that you use `sendMessage()` until you have a fuller understanding of the trials and tribulations that might be involved.

Comment: As an example: [this answer  of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39045023/3773011) presents a simplified view of connecting 1 tab. It is specifically demonstrating issues, particularly timing, involved with connecting just 1 tab. Thus, it does not go into what is needed to manage connections to multiple tabs, as you would need to do in a real add-on. While it uses Firefox, the timing issues also exist in Chrome (just different ones). Using Firefox, it is easier to show the timing issues due to Firefox displaying `console.log` output from both background and content scripts in the same console.

Comment: @wOxxOm     Alright i get what i was missing about the architecture and the  runtime.sendmessage() . I needed to include "activeTab",
    "tabs" in permissions in the manifest.json file and the code for sending message to the currently open tab worked. I am able to send message from the background to the content on clicking the button on the popup. What about vice-versa though? How to send a attach a function to the 'onClick' event of the button on the div that i just added on the content page?

Comment: @Makyen , adding a function onClick inline of the div element gives the error that inline JS can't be executed in extensions::  ' Refused to execute inline event handler because it Refused to execute inline event handler because itfollowing Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self ....''. So how to interact with the div added on the page? How to add JS functions to elements of that div. Also, functions defined in content.js are successfully called by the elements already on the page loaded (not on the div inserted by the extension)

Comment: @BrstDev, Regarding content security policy, [see this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40454989/3773011). If that does not provide enough information to move at least a bit forward, we are going to need to see your new code.

Comment: @Makyen Actually i am able to manage click events for the buttons on the div i just included, by including their click eventListeners code right after i add the div, this way the eventListener for the button looks for the button only after it has been included in the content page and is now a part of the  DOM.